# Atom text editor - force comment/uncomment rather than toggle

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor

I understand Atom has a comment toggle feature using `ctrl + /` but I'd like to know if it's possible to force it on or off rather than toggle. That's because sometimes I have a few lines selected which are a mixture of comments/code and if I use the toggle feature, what is comment becomes code and vice versa. Hence, using the toggle shortcut can be counterproductive sometimes, specially when I'd like to comment out a big part of the code which already has a few comment lines in the middle.

Before Atom I came from Notepad++ and there it's possible to toggle using `ctrl + q` but it's also possible to force comment/uncomment with `ctrl + k` and `ctrl + shift + k` respectively. It would be nice to be able to do the same with Atom, even if I have to download a separate package or something...
Thanks to all!